# Proving measurability of $f$ when $c = \infty .$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The proof is given below:

> [image]

**My question is:**

why we take the intersection of $\{x \in E | f(x) > k\}$ and not the union, could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 2):

Becase if $x$ is in the intersection then $f(x) > k, \forall k \in \Bbb{N}$

Thus $f(x)=+\infty$

If $x$ is in the union thn it just exists $k \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $f(x)>k$

This does not imply that $f(x)=+\infty$ for that $x$